# How to show comments for an unpublished node

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, cck

this is my problem,

- A node is in unpublished state
- The "View own unpublished content" permission is set
- The node author posted a comment on the node, but the comment is not getting rendered in the node page
- The super admin user though can see the comment.

Is this normal in Drupal 7? If so, how can I make those comments visible for the node author?

Hope I can explain my problem, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

1) You may first check and see if the comment is published or not. Comment itself can be pending for approval.

2) I have just tested on Drupal 7 with an unpublished article and adding some comment, they show properly.

3) You may check the template of the node type. Or if you really want to make it and have no other way to do it, use views(not recommended).

Comment: Nope, i recheked with a fresh drupal installation, any comment in an unpublished node by the node author is treated as approved comment, but that is not shown to the node author. However, that is visible to admin. Have you done the comment with a non-admin user?

Comment: I think it is a permission configuration issue.

Comment: I think it is a permission configuration issue. I have install a fresh new Drupal 7. Add a user. Change the article content type to be unpublished when created. Assign authenticated user with following permissions: view comment, add comment, add comment without approval, create article, modify own article, delete own article. View own unpublished node. Login with the user, create an article. Comment on the article, I saw the comment. Remember to clear all cache at this page: admin/config/development/performance

Comment: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/114701/how-to-show-comments-for-an-unpublished-node
https://drupal.org/project/view_unpublished does this